# Java Selenium ChromeDriver SendKeys is really slow

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with Selenium and Chrome. I need to send via SendKeys a really big string (>20'000 characters). It starts very fast, but then it keeps slowing down until it stops sending keys to my body contenteditable=true which i'm referring to by xpath. The browser then is not responding, and I need to kill it via the task manager (I am on Windows 10).

UPDATE: I also tried to send less characters splitting the String and putting some sleeps. The problem is not caused by the amount of character chromedriver has to write, but by the amount of characters in a textbox.

Comment: Avoid using sleeps at all times. You may want to use waits in stead. I don't really see a question here, what are you trying to achieve exactly? Which environment are you working on,...?

Comment: How are using sendKeys() to input the keys? Reading from a file?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use an alternative way to enter characters, by means of JavaScript.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(yourXpath));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText=arguments[1];", element, yourLongText);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Monsignor you should make use of JavaScript. In case you have an Input HTML Element you can also use the following:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(yourXpath));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, yourLongText);
```